# Fast tcp server availability check

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp

I want to make an Unity3D app that has a tcp/ip client. It should check regularly if there is an available server, and if there is one, tries to connect to it. I tried this as following

```
            _client = new TcpClient(_tcpAddress, _tcpPort);
            if (!_client.Connected)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

But every time it calls the constructor, it lags badly. Is there any faster method that checks if there is a server at the specified port?

Comment: `if (_client == null)` would _never_ evaluate to `true`.

Comment: thank you for finding a bug ;) I fixed it to `_client.Connected`. But it still lags badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [specific constructor you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_String_System_Int32_) it states (emphasis mine):

> This constructor creates a new TcpClient and makes a **synchronous connection attempt** to the provided host name and port number. The underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate local IP address and port number. TcpClient **will block** until it either connects or fails. This constructor allows you to initialize, resolve the DNS host name, and connect in one convenient step.

Your code isn't "lagging", it's actively waiting for the connection to succeed or fail.

I would suggest instead using the [default constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor) and either call the [`BeginConnect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143387/fast-tcp-server-availability-check?noredirect=1#comment109907761_62143387) and corresponding [`EndConnect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.endconnect?view=netcore-3.1) methods, or if you can use the async/await pattern in Unity, perhaps try using [`ConnectAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=netcore-3.1).

Although in Unity, I think a simpler method might be to just use a coroutine (I'm not a Unity programmer so this might not be 100% right):

```
StartCoroutine(TestConnectionMethod());

private IEnumerator TestConnectionMethod()
{
     _client = new TcpClient(_tcpAddress, _tcpPort);
     yield return _client.Connected;
}
```